# How to create a bash script in Linux that checks if the user is local or not

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to create a Linux bash script that prompts for a username. For example, it asks for a username, once the username it's typed it will check if the user exists or not. I already tried to do it, but I'm not sure if I did it correctly.
I would appreciate your help.

Here is how I did it:

```
    #!/bin/bash

      echo "Enter your username:"

    read username

    if [ $(getent passwd $username) ] ; then

      echo "The user $username is a local user."

    else

      echo "The user $username is not a local user."

    fi
```

Comment: `getent` will check network logins as well, so this test probably won't be what you want

Comment: At this point, it's all about testing, right. What happens if you user your userID? Does that work, good. What happens if you use something you're sure doesn't exist on your system, maybe `nonesuch` or `ThereIsNoWayThisIsAUserName` or ?? You may also consider looking in `/etc/passwd` to confirm user is "local", but that can vary depending on who/what is responsible for your computing environment. (School, corp, etc, `passwd` file is probably not trustworthy). Good luck.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is for finding solutions to coding problems.  For advice on improving working code, please use [codereview.se] instead.

Comment: What is a local user, what is a non-local user in your scenario?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if grep -q "^${username}:" /etc/passwd; then
      echo "yes the user '$username' exists locally"
fi
```

OR

`getent` command is designed to gather entries for the databases that can be backed by /etc files and various remote services like LDAP, AD, NIS/Yellow Pages, DNS and the likes.

```
if getent passwd "$username" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "yes the user '$username' exists either local or remote"
fi
```

Will do your job, for example below

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter your username:"
read username
if getent passwd "$username" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "yes the user '$username' exists either local or remote"
else
    echo "No, the user '$username' does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: Both approaches will test for all kinds of users, not just the local ones, which is what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following script :

```
user="bob"
if cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | grep -w "$user"; then
    echo "user $user found"
else
    echo "user $user not found"
fi
```

The file `/etc/passwd` contains a list of the local users along with some parameters for them. We use `cut -d: -f1` to only extract the usernames, and match it with our user with `grep -w $user`. The `if` condition evaluate the exit code of the function to determine if the user is present.

Comment: Hmm, my user `bobo` was found, but I don't have a `bob`

Comment: @EricRenouf you are absolutely right, I have to tweak the grep flag to force exact matches

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
USER="userid"

if id $USER > /dev/null 2>&1; then
   echo "user exist!"
else
  echo "user deosn't exist"
fi
```

Comment: OP wanted to test for local users only, so this approach will not work as it will potentially check for domain users as well.