# bash script to check whether a username exists

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I followed the following thread
[How to create a bash script in Linux that checks if the user is local or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42792467/how-to-create-a-bash-script-in-linux-that-checks-if-the-user-is-local-or-not)

I want to check number of arguments number received before checking the username

```
username=$1                                                                     
                                                                                
id -u $username > /dev/null 2>&1                                                
                                                                                
if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then                                                           
 if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then                                                          
  echo "$username exists"                                                       
  else                                                                          
  echo "$username doesn't exist"                                                
  fi                                                                            
else                                                                            
echo "num of arg are less than expected"                                        
fi
```

the script doesn't work properly, it always writes that the user exists

Comment: $? contains exit status of the most recently executed command. `[` is a command, too.

Comment: See [Why is testing "$?" to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36313216/4154375).

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) reports several issues with the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained by Cyrus in comments, you are trying to test `$?` at the wrong place, because the `test` or `[` command set `$?` too.

Better use this:

```
if getent passwd "$username" &>/dev/null; then
    echo 'user exists'
else
    echo 'user NOT exists'
fi
```

The `getent password <username>`, if not match a user, exit with a return code >= 1.
It's boolean logic. No need to test `$?`.

The same logic appears with `id`:

```
id nonexistant || echo "not exists"
```